# What does sample rate mean in audio

Tags: c, linux, audio, sampling, multimedia

see i have one audio track whose sample rate is 44100 then what does it mean ?

what is the duration of one frame of audio? How can i get it in c?

Does frame and sample both are different term for audio?

Comment: Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_rate

Comment: The only question in there that could be on topic here is "How can I get it in C?", but it's not well defined enough - you'd need to specify what format your data is in at least. (Also, please, capital letters are important for readability.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sample of audio is similar to a frame of video, it's a capture of the sound level at a particular time point, in the same way as a frame of video is a capture of the light pattern. A frame rate of 44,100 is 44,100 samples per SECOND, or 44.1 kHz. So a sample duration is 1/44,100 seconds = 2.26e-5 seconds.

We can hear sounds in the approximate range 20 Hz to 20 kHz, so the sample rate needs to be very high to capture that information accurately enough to reproduce it without too many artifacts.